# Refresh previous page

Tags: php, javascript, file, download, refresh

I have website that produces a csv to be downloaded after some user input. http://splice.cmi.arizona.edu/splice_file_upload/fileupload.php

The page works in giving me a csv, the problem I do have is that after downloading the csv, I want the original page to refresh (or at least get rid of the text that a file has been uploaded).

I tried calling onclick on the submit button to run some javascript, but that doesn't seem to be working.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: try form's `submit` event? or `<form onsubmit="your code here">`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
document.location.href = 'http://splice.cmi.arizona.edu/splice_file_upload/fileupload.php';
```

after the submit event?

Answer (score 0):

Hmz, try this code out:

**JS**

```
window.onload=function(){document.forms['analyses'].lastChild.previousSibling.onclick=function(){setTimeout(function(){location.reload(true);},1000);return true;};};
```

Just add this js anywhere in the page :-? should work. If not... post errors.

P.S. This is a horrible way of making the page refresh after you click submit.

The simplest solution would actually be to clear that zone after you click submit.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you can use

```
window.location="your current page to reopen e.g. fileupload.php"
```

or in PHP,

```
<?php header("Location: fileupload.php");?>
```

In general, after completing download action, simply redirect to the same page.